# Convergence of Sobolev functions near the boundary

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $B_0(1)$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$, $n\geq2$. Let $f\in W_0^{1,2}(B_0(1))$, and $W^{1,2}(B_0(1))\ni f_i\to f$ in the sense of $L^2(B_0(1))$-norm, as $i\to \infty$.

> **Question 1**: Can we find a sequence of positive numbers $\{\delta_i\}$ (may depends on $\{f_i\}$), going to $0$, s.t., $$\frac{1}{\delta_i^2}\int_{1-\delta_i\leq|x|\leq1}f_i^2\,dx\to0,$$
>   as $i\to\infty$ ?

> **Question 2**: If Question 1 is not true, we then strengthen the condition that $W^{1,2}(B_0(1))\ni f_i\to f$ in the sense of $W^{1,2}(B_0(1))$-norm. Can we prove Question 1's conclusion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Question 1 has a positive answer. Denote $B=:B_0(1)$ and $A_r:=\{r<\|x\|<1\} $ for  $0<r<1$. For  functions $f\in W^{1,2}_0(B)$ we have a Poincaré inequality on $A_r$ :
$$\int_{A_r} f^2dx\le \Big(\frac{1-r}{r}\Big)^2 \int_{A_r} |\nabla f|^2dx \ .$$

Now let $(f_i)$ a sequence in $W^{1,2}(B)$ converging to $f$, so $f^2_i$ converges to $f^2$ in $L^1(B)$. For any sequence $0<\delta_i<1$ we have, by the above inequality:

$$\frac{1}{\delta_i^2}\int_{A_{1-\delta_i}}f_i^2dx\le \frac{1}{\delta_i^2}\int_{A_{1-\delta_i}}f ^2dx + \frac{1}{\delta_i^2} \|f^2-f_i^2\|_{1} \le$$

$$\le \frac{1}{ (1-\delta_i)^2} \int_{A_{1-\delta_i}}\|\nabla f\| ^2dx + \frac{1}{\delta_i^2} \|f^2-f_i^2\|_1\ .$$

Now if  $\delta_i=o(1)$, the first term on the RHS is $o(1)$, just because $\|\nabla f\| ^2$ is integrable and $\operatorname{meas}(A_{1-\delta_i})=o(1)$.

On the other hand, if we also choose the sequence $\delta_i$ such that $  \|f^2-f_i^2\|_1=o(\delta_i^2)$ as $i\to\infty$, the other term is also $o(1)$.

$$*$$

*Details on the above Poincaré inequality.*  By density, one can assume $f\in C^\infty_c(B)$. Let  $0<r\le \|x\|\le 1$. So $f(x/r)=0$, and we have
$$f(x)= -\int_1^{1/r}\partial_t f(tx)dt=-\int_1^{1/r}\nabla f(tx)\cdot x\ dt\ . $$ 
Thus by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$ f(x) ^2\le \Big(\frac{1}{r} -1\Big)  \int_1^{1/r}\|\nabla f(tx)\|^2 dt\ , $$ 
and 
$$ \int_{A_r} f(x) ^2 \ dx\le \Big(\frac{1}{r} -1\Big)   \int_{A_r}\int_1^{1/r}\|\nabla f(tx)\|^2 \ dt\ dx =  $$
$$=\Big(\frac{1}{r} -1\Big)   \int_1^{1/r} t^{-n} \int_{A_{tr}} \|\nabla f( x)\|^2 \ dx \ dt  $$
$$\le \Big(\frac{1}{r} -1\Big)^2    \int_{A_{r}} \|\nabla f( x)\|^2 \ dx  \ .  $$

Answer (score 1):

The answer to Q1 is *yes.* As pointed out by both Pietro and me in [this very similar question,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226922/convergence-of-energy-of-sobolev-functions-near-the-boundary/226930#226930) we will have that
$$
\frac{1}{\delta^2}\int_{1-\delta\le |x|\le 1} f^2\, dx \to 0 ,
$$
since $f\in W^{1,2}_0(B)$.

Take $\sigma_k$ so small that this is $<1/k$ for $\delta\le\sigma_k$. Then also
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma_k^2}\int_{1-\sigma_k\le |x|\le 1} f_n^2 < \frac{1}{k}
$$
for all large $n\ge N=N_k$ by $L^2$ convergence. We can also assume that the $N_k$ increase and $\sigma_k\to 0$, and now we can define $\delta_n$ to be $\sigma_k$ for $N_k\le n<N_{k+1}$.

Comment: This also says that the sequence $\delta_k$ must converge to $0$ not too fast. For instance, keeping fixed $\sigma_k$,  any other $N_k'\ge N_k$ works as well, and the corresponding $\delta_n'$ would converge to $0$ slowly (just to check the conclusion I got).

Comment: @PietroMajer: Yes, I think we are saying the same thing in our answers. Before I can make $\delta_n$ smaller, I must wait for $\int_{1-\delta\le |x| \le 1} f_n^2$ to become sufficiently small, with the new $\delta$.

Comment: Both answers are so useful, thank you so much. I find that I could not accept two answers at the same time.