# $\int\limits_{\Omega}{uvdx}<\infty,\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ implies $u\in L^{6/5}(\Omega)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

I posted this question first in Math.StackExchange one week ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1596096/254733), but I didn't get an answer or a helpful comment so I repost it here:

Let $d=3$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain and $u$ is a measurable function.
A sufficient condition for the integral $\int\limits_{\Omega}{uvdx}<\infty,\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is that $u\in L^{6/5}(\Omega)$ which follows from Holder's inequality and the (continuous) embedding $H^1(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^6(\Omega)$.

**Question:** Is the opposite true, i.e is it true that
$$\int\limits_{\Omega}{uvdx}<\infty,\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$$ implies $u\in L^{6/5}(\Omega)$ or at least $u\in L^1(\Omega)$ ?

**My thoughts:** It is easy to see that $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ by taking $v$ to be smooth cut-off functions equal to $1$ in compact subsets of $\Omega$ and $0$ in a neighborhood of the boundary $\partial \Omega$.

The motivation for this question is the "correct" weak formulation of a nonlinear problem - whether to formulate it as $(1)$ or as $(2)$:

$(1)$ Find $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that $f(u)\in L^{6/5}(\Omega)$ and 
$$a(u,v)+\int\limits_{\Omega}{f(u)vdx}=0,\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$$

or

$(2)$ Find $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that $\int\limits_{\Omega}{f(u)vdx}<\infty,\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and 
$$a(u,v)+\int\limits_{\Omega}{f(u)vdx}=0,\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$$

where $a(.,.)$ is a bilinear form and $f(.)$ is in general a nonlinear function. If the answer to my question is affirmative then both formulations are equivalent.

Note that $(2)$ is less restrictive, because the set in which we search for a solution is bigger, so it might be easier to find such.

Comment: You are asking if $H^{-1} \subset L^{6/5}$, which is false

Comment: @Piero D'Ancona Can you give me some argument or a reference, so that I can see why is this?

Comment: Take $u=\partial_1(\chi(x)v(x_1))$ where $\chi$ is a test function on $R^3$ equal to 1 near the origin and $v(s)$ is the sign function. From $\chi v\in L^2$ it follows $u\in H^{-1}$, and of course $u$ is not even a function since it is a distribution (a delta in the direction $x_1$).

Comment: @Piero D'Ancona Yes, this is fine, but my functional is not just any functional (distribution) but it is a regular distribution, i.e it is represented by an integral of the measurable function $u(x)$ times a function $v(x)\in H_0^1$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That doesn't work because $H_0^1$ functions are small near the boundary, so testing against them won't detect bad behavior of $u$ near $\partial\Omega$.

For a concrete example, take $\Omega$ as the unit ball and $u(x)=1/(1-|x|)\notin L^1$. Then
$$
\int |uv|\, dx \le \left( \int \frac{v^2\, dx}{(1-|x|)^{3/2}} \int \frac{dx}{(1-|x|)^{1/2}} \right)^{1/2} .
$$
If $v\in H_0^1$ is also smooth, then we can estimate the first integral in the same way as in this [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226965/convergence-of-sobolev-functions-near-the-boundary/226985#226985) (by just integrating the gradient, starting from the boundary, to bound $v$). This gives $\int v^2/(1-|x|)^{3/2}\lesssim \|v\|^2_{H^1}$, so $\int |uv| \lesssim \|v\|_{H^1}$ for all such $v$, and by density of the smooth functions, this also holds for arbitrary $v\in H_0^1$.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I like your answer, but I cann't get the crucial inequality $|v(x)|\leq (1-|x|)^{1/2}\|v\|_{H_0^1}$. Could you elaborate a bit on it ?

Comment: If I understand correctly the issue, I think that this inequality can not be true (for $C_0^\infty$ functions), because (I think) there are positive functions $f\in C_0^\infty(B_0(1))$ with arbitrary small $H^1$ norm and arbitrary "high": $\forall M>0\forall \delta>0\exists f\in H_0^1(B_0(1)): \|f\|_{H^1(B_0(1))}<\delta$ and $\exists \epsilon>0: f(x)\ge M$ a.e in $B_0(\epsilon)\subset B_0(1)$. For example, if we take $g=K \log{\frac{1}{|x|/\epsilon}}$ and construct the function $\tilde g=g$ on $B_0(\epsilon)$ and $\tilde g=0$ on $B_0(1)\setminus B_0(\epsilon)$. Here $K$ controls the $H^1$-norm

Comment: Then, if $h(x)=\tilde g(x)$ where $x: \tilde g(x)\leq M$ and $h(x)=M$ where $x: \tilde g(x)\ge M$. Now taking $f$ to be a mollified version of $h$ should give us $C_0^\infty(B_0(1))$ function, for which the inequality does not hold. Maybe I am missing something, but it will be nice if you check my construction.

Comment: A simple example is the standard mollifier: $f_\epsilon(x)=\exp{\left( \frac{1}{\left(\frac{|x|}{\epsilon} \right)^2-1}\right)}$ for small enough $\epsilon$ (

$\epsilon=0.1$ or $0.01$ will do the job.)

Comment: @Svetoslav: Yes, I need to do it slightly differently, but the bottom line stays the same (edited now).

Comment: I still can not show the inequality for $v\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. Could you please add  2-3 explanatory lines about the inequality. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Svetoslav: As in Pietro's answer (linked question), I use the inequality $v^2(x)\lesssim (1-|x|)\int_{1/2}^1 \| \nabla v(x) \|^2 \, dr$ for $|x|\ge 1/2$, say; the integration is over the radial variable $r=|x|$. If I now also integrate over the angle, then the resulting integral is estimated by $\|v\|^2_{H^1}$. There is one more integration over a radial variable (the outer $x$), but this just affects the constant. (For $x$ not close to the boundary, I can just estimate those contributions to $\int |uv|$ directly by $C\|v\|_{L^2}$.)

Comment: I understand that away from the boundary $\int\limits_{B_1\setminus A_{1/2}}{|uv|dx}\leq \|u\|_{L^2(B_1\setminus A_{1/2})}\|v\|_{L^2(B_1\setminus A_{1/2})}\leq C\|v\|_{L^2(B_1(0))}\leq C\|v\|_{H^1(B_1(0))}$. But for $|x|\ge 1/2$ I can not get  the inequality $v^2(x)\leq C(1-|x|)\int\limits_{1/2}^{1}{|\nabla v(x)|^2}dr$ or whatever the inequality is (above we integrate $|\nabla v(x)|^2$ which does not depend on the radial variable)

Comment: I do like Pietro does in his answer, but now I have instead of a fixed $r$, $|x|$ which causes me the problems:
$$v(x)=v(x)-v(x/|x|)=-\int\limits_{1}^{1/|x|}{\nabla f(tx)\cdot x dt}\Rightarrow$$
$$v^2(x)\leq \left(\frac{1}{|x|}-1\right)\int\limits_{1}^{1/|x|}{|\nabla f(tx)|^2dt}\Rightarrow$$
$$\int\limits_{A_{1/2}}{\frac{v^2(x)}{(1-|x|)^{3/2}}dx}\leq \int\limits_{A_{1/2}}{\frac{1}{(1-|x|)^{1/2}|x|}\int\limits_{1}^{1/|x|}{|\nabla f(tx)|^2dt}dx}\leq $$ $$\int\limits_{A_{1/2}}{\left(\frac{1}{(1-|x|)^{1/2}}\int\limits_{1}^{1/|x|}{| \nabla f(tx)|^2dt}\right)dx}$$

Comment: So the problem is to estimate the last integral by $\|v\|_{H^1(B_1)}$

Comment: Notice that the $t$ integration is essentially the same thing as integrating with respect to the radial variable in spherical coordinates, so integrating over just the angular part of $dx$ gives you a quantity that is estimated by $\|v\|^2$, and then the extra $d|x|$ integration just affects the constant.

Comment: I have now another question.  It is not clear how we are passing to the inequality : $\int {|uv|dx}\leq C\|v\|_{H^1(B_1)}$. I guess by: Let $v\in H_0^1(B_1)$ is arbitrary. Then  $\exists \{v_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset C_0^\infty(B_1): \, \|v_n-v\|_{H^1(B_1)}\to 0$. So by passing to a limit in the inequality $\int {|uv_n|dx}\leq C\|v_n\|_{H^1(B_1)}$ we get that the right hand side tends to $C\|v\|_{H^1(B_1)}$, but the  LHS is problematic. First I thought to use Cauchy/Holder inequality, but then realized that $u\notin L^1$. Then I tried DCT  and Vitali Th. but again with no success.

Comment: @Svetoslav: I think Fatou's Lemma works best here: we also have that $v_n\to v$ pointwise a.e. (pass to a subsequence if necessary), so $\int |uv|=\int\liminf |uv_n|\le\liminf\int|uv_n|\lesssim \liminf\|v_n\|=\|v\|$.

Comment: Please excuse me for asking for $n$-th time. Can I conclude from $\int{f}$ is finite, that $f\in L^1$. 

More precisely, here I use the following definition for the Lebesgue integral: If $f$ is measurable, then $\int{f}=\int{f^+}-\int{f^-}$, where $f^+,f^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $f$. So, if I use this definition, and $\int{f}$ is finite, it should follow that both $\int{f^+},\int{f^-}$ are finite, and so $\int{|f|}<\infty$. I am asking, because of the condition I put on $\int{f(u)vdx}$ to be finite. Does it follow that $f(u)v\in L^1$  ?

Comment: @Svetoslav: Normally it's done the other way around: for measurable $f$, $f\in L^1$ means that $\int |f|<\infty$ (this makes sense because if $g\ge 0$ is measurable, then $\int g$ is defined, possibly $=\infty$), and then IF $f\in L^1$, we may define $\int f$ also. I'm not sure you can meaningfully impose a condition "$\int uv$ finite" that is different from the obvious (and my) interpretation "$\int |uv|$ finite."